# search all telegram channels where username (@xxxx) containing a specific keyword with Telethon library

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm trying to find use the Python Telethon library to find all channels where the Username (ex.@xxxxxxx) contains a user-inputted keyword. I'm using the below code for this purpose, but for some reason, it's not giving all the results that I want. For example, if i type "sonic", it's giving me these results:

https://t.me/sonicboyofficial
https://t.me/SONICc29

[image: tele pic]

I was hoping that the results would have this channel:

https://t.me/sonicsnipereth

but it's not part of the output. does anyone know what i can do to improve this script?

```
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions
import configparser
import os, json


def parse_api():

    """Read the hash from config file"""

    config_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    read_config = config_parser.read("api.ini")
    if not read_config:
        """Write api id and hash in the api.ini file if not found"""
        print("If you do not have api id and api hash, please get them from https://my.telegram.org/")
        write_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config_parser.add_section("API_CONFIG")
        api_id = input("Enter api id:")
        api_hash = input("Enter api hash:")
        # set the configs
        config_parser.set("API_CONFIG","api_id",api_id.strip())
        config_parser.set("API_CONFIG","api_hash",api_hash.strip())
        
        with open('api.ini', 'w') as api:
            config_parser.write(api)

    else:
        config_parser.read("api.ini")
        api_id = config_parser.get("API_CONFIG", "api_id")
        api_hash = config_parser.get("API_CONFIG", "api_hash")
    return api_id, api_hash

api_id, api_hash = parse_api()
    
client = TelegramClient("search", api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))
    print("""
         ====================================================
          Welcome to Searching telegram groups/channels
          with search query.
          =======================================================
        """)
    while True:
    
        search = input("Please enter search query:")
        result = await client(functions.contacts.SearchRequest(
        q=search,
        limit=2000
        ))
        d = result.to_dict()

        usernames = []
        for item in d['chats']:
            usernames.append(item['username'])
        if not usernames:
            print()
            print()
            print("No groups found. try again?")
            
        for username in usernames:
            print("https://t.me/"+username)
            """Saving to GroupList.txt file for auto joining"""
            with open("GroupList.txt", "+a") as gl:
                gl.write("https://t.me/"+username)
                gl.write("\n")
        print()
        print("File Saved to "+os.getcwd())
        choice = input("You wanna searching more..., press(y):")
        print()
        if choice != "y":
            break
    
       
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```